# How to post image to friend's Facebook wall

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

```
NSData* imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.qqqimage, 90);
NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                self.messegeSend.text, @"message",
                                imageData, @"source",
                                nil];

postPath = [postPath stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@/feed",[friendList objectAtIndex:i]] ;

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:postPath
                             parameters:params
                             HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
 {
```

This is my code , but get error `http 200`

I also try `postPath` with `@"%@/photos",friendID` , but http 200 again

Comment: http 200 means that your request has been completed succesfully, see this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: 200=OK ! Did you actually check the image on the feed ?

Comment: I know 200=OK , but I don't know what's wrong.
How I can check the image on the feed ?

Comment: My error is Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x9d11540 {com.facebook.sdk:ErrorInnerErrorKey=Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL" UserInfo=0x9dd06d0 {NSUnderlyingError=0xf9bf8e0 "bad URL", NSLocalizedDescription=bad URL},